# FileRepresentation returning file with name coming from the router.attach

Tags: java, restlet

Here's a weird one. I need to use the `restlet api` to download a file. I'm creating the file in the `GET` method and returning a `FileRepresentation`. The download works fine, but the file name is always coming from the name of the operation specified in `ApplicationRoot`.

This is the relevant line in my `ApplicationRoot`:

```
router.attach("/LogDownload",LogDataDownload.class);
```

And the relevant method in `LogDataDownload`:

```
@Get
public Representation run() {

    APIResponseWrapper wrapper = new APIResponseWrapper(null, true);
    try{
        String fileLogPath = Config.getLogFilePath();
        File logFile = new File(fileLogPath);
        return FileUtility.createRepForFile(logFile);
    }catch(Exception e){
        wrapper.setErrorStackTrace(e);
    }
    return new JacksonRepresentation<APIResponseWrapper>(wrapper);
}
```

This is how I'm creating the `FileRepresentation`:

```
public static FileRepresentation createRepForFile(File file) {
    MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
    String mimeTypeStr = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
    MediaType mt = new MediaType(mimeTypeStr);
    FileRepresentation fr = new FileRepresentation(file, mt);
    fr.setDisposition(new Disposition(Disposition.TYPE_ATTACHMENT));
    return fr;
}
```

The download works with no problem through this url: `http://server:port/AppName/LogDownload`

but the downloaded file name is always `LoadDownload` (or whatever I put in the `router.attach` line) and I'm unable to rename it to what I want, which in this case would be `logFile.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to set the `Disposition` correctly. Here's the full method:

```
public static FileRepresentation createRepForFile(File file) {
    MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
    String mimeTypeStr = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
    MediaType mt = new MediaType(mimeTypeStr);
    FileRepresentation fr = new FileRepresentation(file, mt);

    Disposition disp = new Disposition(Disposition.TYPE_ATTACHMENT); 
    disp.setFilename(file.getName()); 
    disp.setSize(file.length()); 
    fr.setDisposition(disp); 

    return fr;
}
```